# org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "errorMessages" (Class ReasonDTO), not marked as ignorable

Tags: json

I am trying to parse the returned JSON from a REST service call back into the DTO object so it can be used on the client side.  The client code looks like:

```
@Test
public void retrieveAllReasonsUsingJSONandGet() throws Exception {
    List<Object> providers = new ArrayList<Object>();
    providers.add(new org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider());

    WebClient client = WebClient.create(endpointUrl + "/retrieveall", providers);

    Response r = client.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get();
    assertEquals(Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode(), r.getStatus());

    MappingJsonFactory factory = new MappingJsonFactory();
    JsonParser parser = factory.createJsonParser((InputStream)r.getEntity());
    TypeReference<List<ReasonDTO>> ref = new TypeReference<List<ReasonDTO>>() {} ;
    List<ReasonDTO> allReasons = (List<ReasonDTO>) parser.readValueAs(ref);

    assertEquals(43, allReasons.size());
} // retrieveAllReasonsUsingJSONandGet
```

One stanza of the returned JSON (there are 43 of them) looks like:

```
{
    "reasonCode": "...",
    "reason": "...",
    "hasError": false,
    "errorMessages": [],
    "hasWarning": false,
    "warningMessages": []
},
```

The DTO object look like (ignore the XML stuff since the same DTOs are passed back using JAX-WS so they need to be marshalled/unmarshalled as XML too):

```
public class ReasonDTO {
    private String reasonCode;
    private String reason;
    private boolean hasError = false;
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "errorMessages")
    @XmlElement(name = "errorMessage")
    private List<String> errorMessages = new ArrayList<String>();
    private boolean hasWarning = false;
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "warningMessages")
    @XmlElement(name = "warningMessage")
    private List<String> warningMessages = new ArrayList<String>();
```

The full exception that is getting thrown is:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "errorMessages" (Class ReasonDTO), not marked as ignorable
 at [Source: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@29b429b4; line: 1, column: 91] (through reference chain: ReasonDTO["errorMessages"])
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.unknownFieldException(StdDeserializationContext.java:248)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializer.reportUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:542)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:528)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializer.java:671)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:519)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:350)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:93)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:25)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1961)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:852)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser.readValueAs(JsonParser.java:1118)
    at TE_ReasonREST_ServiceTester.retrieveAllReasonsUsingJSONandPost(TE_ReasonREST_ServiceTester.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

The error message seems to be saying that the "errorMessages" field isn't found in the DTO, but mine is there.  The other posts I have read about this suggest to use

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties
```

but I don't want to ignore the errorMessage since if there are some present, they indicate problems.

Any thoughts as to what my problem might be and where I should look for solutions?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I solved it:

```
@JsonDeserialize(as=ArrayList.class, contentAs=String.class)
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "warningMessages")
@XmlElement(name = "warningMessage")
private List<String> warningMessages = new ArrayList<String>();
```

**@JsonDeserialize(as=ArrayList.class, contentAs=String.class)**

EDIT-

```
package com.company.client.hibernate.helper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonDeserialize;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ResultDTO {
    private boolean hasError = false; 
    @JsonDeserialize(as=ArrayList.class, contentAs=String.class) 
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "errorMessages") 
    @XmlElement(name = "errorMessage") 
    private List<String> errorMessages = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    private boolean hasWarning = false; 
    @JsonDeserialize(as=ArrayList.class, contentAs=String.class) 
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "warningMessages") 
    @XmlElement(name = "warningMessage") 
    private List<String> warningMessages = new ArrayList<String>(); 

    public boolean isHasError() { 
        return hasError; 
    }
    public void setHasError(boolean hasError) { 
        this.hasError = hasError; 
    }
    public List<String> getErrorMessages() { 
        return this.errorMessages; 
    }
    public void addErrorMessage(String errorMessage) { 
        this.errorMessages.add(errorMessage); 
    }
    public boolean isHasWarning() { 
        return this.hasWarning; 
    }
    public void setHasWarning(boolean hasWarning) { 
        this.hasWarning = hasWarning; 
    }
    public List<String> getWarningMessages() { 
        return this.warningMessages; 
    }
    public void addWarningMessage(String warningMessage) { 
        this.warningMessages.add(warningMessage); 
    }  
}
```

Comment: Could you tell me where do you insert those lines that fixed your problem please?

Comment: Jon - I added an edit to my solution above to give complete context around the solution.  I annotated each field inside of the DTO object being returned to tell Jackson that the item was an ArrayList of Strings.